# How to run external command in Symfony console?

Tags: php, exec, symfony-console

I have this Symfony console class.

```
<?php


namespace System\Core\Console;

use \Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use \Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class Test extends \Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command
{


    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('test')
            ->setDescription('Just for test execute external command such as "composer update".');
    }// configure


    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        exec('composer update 2>&1');
        $output->writeln('Success!');
    }// execute


}
```

After run the command <kbd>php myapp.php test</kbd> then I got this result.

```
me@Mycom C:\wwwroot\myapp
> php myapp.php test
Success!
| <<--hang on blinking here!
```

It was frozen by blinking at the last line and I cannot start new command until <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>.

How to execute "external" program in Symfony Console?

My Symfony Console version is v.3.latest.

Comment: Try to use Symfony Process component inside your command class https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html